# Ahoy gem filtering visit_token/visitor_token. Geolocation is NOT storing data in development/production database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, ahoy

###### The Ahoy gem is simply not storing any geo-location data in the database, and is returning `[FILTERED]` as the value for the `visit_token` and `visitor_token`.

[image]

### File Setup:

##### rails_app/Gemfile:

`ruby "3.1.0"` 
`gem "ahoy_matey"` 
`gem "geocoder"` 
`gem "maxminddb"` 
`gem "rails", "~> 7.0.3", ">= 7.0.3.1"` 
`gem "pg", "~>1.1"`

##### Ran the following commands from root of project:

`bundle install` 
`rails generate ahoy:install` 
`rails db:migrate`

##### rails_app/config/initializers/GeoLite2/:

###### `=> GeoLite2-City.mmdb`

##### rails_app/config/initializers/geocoder.rb:

`Geocoder.configure(` 
  `ip_lookup: :geoip2,` 
  `geoip2: {` 
    `file: "./GeoLite2/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"` 
  `}`
`)`

##### rails_app/config/initializers/ahoy.rb:

`class Ahoy::Store < Ahoy::DatabaseStore`
`end`

`# set to true for JavaScript tracking`
`Ahoy.api = false`

`# set to true for geocoding (and add the geocoder gem to your Gemfile)`
`# we recommend configuring local geocoding as well`
`# see https://github.com/ankane/ahoy#geocoding`
`Ahoy.geocode = true`
`Ahoy.job_queue = :low_priority`

##### rails_app/config/importmap.rb:

`pin "ahoy", to: "ahoy.js"`

##### rails_app/app/javascript/application.js:

`import "ahoy"`